# Open source advertising: can I advertise something that is not my project?

Tags: discussion, advertising, open-source-advertising

I noticed [Open Source Advertising Sidebar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/210389) long time ago, but only recently I started to look how can I get to advertise something. I read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210389/202038) and based on requirements:

> It must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and
>   contribution of programmers writing actual source code. This is not
>   intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just
>   happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help
>   contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code
>   review, bug fixes, etc.).
>
> Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously
>   appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have
>   appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

as I understood that I can actually create and advertisement for a project that I like (but I am not a creator of this project), and is an open source. Am I correct?

By I am not a creator I mean - I am not a creator, contributor, have no connection to neither creator nor any of the contributors. It just happened that I found the project and think that it is amazing.

Comment: While not common I can't see anything wrong about it. Go ahead! :)

Comment: @Salvador Dali . It would make a lot of sense to _co-ordinate_ with the project team you want to promote. They would like some warning of extra traffic. Perhaps they want to garden their 'to do' list to make it easy for new contributors to choose a task. And they would certainly want to avoid website maintenance on the day the ad goes live, and have someone available (on the mailing list / IRC / social media) to answer newbie questions. (Some open source projects actually dislike external contributions, though that is rare.)